# What does the openfileDialog.OpenFile method do exactly in the namespace System.Windows.Forms

Tags: c#

I am trying to learn C# and then I came across the OpenfileDialog.OpenFile method.The URL is here :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile?view=netcore-3.1
Now my confusion is here. The description of the method says : Opens the file selected by the user, with read-only permission. The file is specified by the FileName property.

One Question :
1. I was assuming that when a user selects a file, the filename ie C:\word.docx is stored as a String in this FileName property and that the OpenFile method returns in fact a string that gets stored in the FileName property. However I see in the documentation it returns A Stream that specifies the read-only file selected by the user. So I'm really confused what is happening here. I read it one way and all I need to do is grab the contents of the FileName property. What is this stream then and what should I do with that?

Thanks a lot

Frank

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Comment: Have you looked at the example there? It shows `ShowDialog()` being used first to set the `FileName` property and *then* using the `OpenFile` method to get the contents of the file.

Comment: The OpenFile() method does not store a filename anywhere, the ShowDialog() method will do that for you. You won't need OpenFile() to use the filename, your OpenFileDialog instance will have a string property **openFileDialog1.FileName**, refer to the example in microsoft docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-open-files-using-the-openfiledialog-component

Comment: *"I was assuming that ... OpenFile method returns ... a string that gets stored in the FileName property"* - wrong assumption. Refer to [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile) often. You can simply use same property after dialog is closed (make sure to check return value of `ShowDialog()`) to get file name selected by the user.

Comment: My apologies Sweeper. Ok Damien. But Ithink that's what I didn't understandAs I see it ShowDialog() doesn't return the filename it returns ok abort and stuff. The openFile method returns a stream which can or cannot be captured and also the filename property  has a string with the path to the filename.

Comment: Don't just apologise :) You can [edit] your question to remove one of the questions. Then I can write an answer. You can also use "@username" to reply to someone.

Comment: And your understanding is correct. `ShowDialog` indeed does not return the file name. `OpenFile` indeed returns a `Stream`. `FileName` indeed stores the path. What don't you understand then? And what do you mean by "which can or cannot be captured"?

Comment: Thanks Sweeper I thought I was on to something there, but thanks for verifying this. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

When you click F12 on metod takes you to class.
If you click F12 on OpenFileDialog you can see it inherits FileDialog. Click again F12 on this class, and next it inherits CommonDialog. There is method ShowDialog();